# Как определить город юзера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, google-maps-api

В последнее время вижу много сайтов, которые при открытии выдают модальное окно с предполагаемым городом и выбором другого, если определенно неверно.

Как собственно реализовать такую штуку у себя на сайте?
Что для этого используется js и api какой-то карты?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://sypexgeo.net/

Вот еще один простой пример

```
$server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$rrs = file_get_contents("http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/".$server);
$obj = json_decode($rrs);
$country = $obj->country->name_ru;
```

Answer (score 4):

Можете использовать Yandex API. В данном примере загружаются два скрипта: `ymaps` и `jQuery` для удобства. Когда `ymaps` загружен, в глобальном контексте появляется одноименный объект ymaps. Из него то и можно получить то, что Вам нужно. Например город: `ymaps.geolocation.city`. Или регион: `ymaps.geolocation.region`. Все просто! Так же Вы можете распечатать в консоли объект `console.log(ymaps);` и посмотреть все его свойства и методы.

```
<script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
      jQuery("#user-city").text(ymaps.geolocation.city);
      jQuery("#user-region").text(ymaps.geolocation.region);
      jQuery("#user-country").text(ymaps.geolocation.country);
  }
</script>

<div id="user-city"></div> <div id="user-region"></div> <div id="user-
country"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

По IP со стороны сервера можно определить расположение вашего провайдера. Для более точного определения вашего расположения можно использовать [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). В этом случае браузер запросит подтверждение.