# Переадресация по городу

Tags: joomla, ip, joomla3

Нужно что бы при заходе на сайте человека автоматически перенаправляло на страницу его города определенного по ip. Подскажите как это сделать? Возможно какое-то расширение или код?

Comment: Можно запоминать пару ip - город, и когда набьется БД городов - перестанет спрашивать. Но на один ip могут быть и разные города.

Comment: О, вопрос уже был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693982/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0 не думаю что переписать ответ на joomla составит затруднения.

Comment: Можно плагин написать, проблем не вижу. А страницы для городов на этом же домене или на поддомене?